# How can get PDF::API2 to use CMYK instead of RGB?

Tags: perl, pdf

I am generating pdfs with Perl and PDF::API2.  How can I get my pdf to be CMYK?  Currently my pdfs all come out as RGB according to ImageMagick's identify command.

Comment: Go through this link which might be hlpful    http://search.cpan.org/~areibens/PDF-API2-0.73/lib/PDF/API2/HOWTO.pod#C-M-Y-K

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PDF::API2 allows colors to be entered as RGB or CMYK](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PDF%3a%3aAPI2%3a%3aContent#colors), and will output whatever you pass into it.

To enter a CMYK color, use the pattern `%CCMMYYKK` instead of `#RRGGBB` (note the percent sign instead of the number sign).

For example, you can set "true black" as follows:

```
$content->fillcolor('%000000FF');
```

PDF::API2::Util also has an undocumented RGBtoCMYK function.  I have no idea if it's accurate, and it's undocumented, so use at your own risk, but it might be useful as a one-time way to convert your existing RGB colors to CMYK.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  But what about images?  Do I need to make each image cmyk before inserting it?  Can a pdf be composed of rgb and cmyk components?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to convert images to CMYK beforehand, and yes, you can mix and match colorspaces.  Look into your requirements, though.  Why do you need to convert images to CMYK?  It only tends to matter for graphics/print shops -- otherwise the printer should do a good enough job on its own.  Graphics pros should be giving you CMYK images to start with if they care about color matching.  Otherwise, they're just trading one arbitrary color conversion (the printer) for another (your software), and the printer will probably give a better match.